# Redirect Serial Output to SSH or Local File - Device Lacks Serial Port and Being Accessed via SSH

Tags: port, jailhouse

Hi guys my problem is as follows:

**Environment** - Im in a windows machine and connected via ssh to an ubuntu machine that is running a hypervisor https://github.com/siemens/jailhouse alongside ubuntu.

**Problem:**
The hypervisor in question dumps debug and "cell"(like guest VM's but not quite) outputs to a serial port, and the physical machine that is running the hypervisor **lacks a serial port**.

**What I need to know if it is possible:**
I wish to redirect that serial output to SSH back to me or dump to a file that I can "nano" later.

Thanks in advance 
Regards
André Santos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The reason is that the output is written by the hypervisor, not by the operating system, through a specific serial driver implemented in the hypervisor itself.

Thus, the hypervisor does not have knowledge of the Linux filesystem, nor of the Linux drivers, and the only channels that it can use are a 8250-compliant serial line or (in case of x86) the VGA.

Side note: depending on your particular needs, you may want to wrap the Jailhoused Linux through an additional Qemu/KVM virtual machine. In this case, the output of Jailhouse (exceuted by the guest machine) is written on the console of the host machine, and it can be easily retrievable through the SSH connection.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I'm not in such project anymore as this question was asked more than one year ago with no answers or comments until today. I'll mark your answer as correct.